# Is this function with cases complex differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

$$
f(z)=
\begin{cases}
    \overline{\sin(\overline{z})},& \text{if } \Im z \geq 0, \\
    \sin(z),& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Is $f$ differentiable at $z_0 = \frac \pi 2$?

---

Can someone help me solve this? My problem is that I don't know how to treat the cases. Would I just treat them "separately"?

And even if so, my idea would be to use Cauchy Riemann. But how can I calculate the partial derivates for this function...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\sin z =\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nz^{2n-1}$ for all complex numbers $z$, where $a_n=\frac {(-1)^{n}} {(2n-1)!}$. Compute $\overline{\sin(\overline{z})}$ from this equation and you will see that $f(z)$ is nothing but $\sin z$ for all $z$. So $f$ is differentiable at all points.